# Replicate T-SQL DecryptByPassPhrase in C#

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, 3des

I wnat to create a C# class to decrypt a byte array encrypted using T-SQL's EncryptByPassPhrase.  (Yes, I know I could decrypt within SQL Server, but what I need is to be able to encrypt/decrypt within both the database tier and in the middle tier equivalently.)

I understand that SQL Server's EncryptByPassPhrase and DecryptByPassPhrase use the TripleDES symmetric key algorithm.  It's not clear to me, though, what the IV should to simulate SQL Server's cryptology.  I can encrypt/decrypt using the [TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx) class, but I can't find the correct implementation of key and IV to replicate what SQL Server is doing.

Has anyone done something similar?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a public repo on github that recreates `EncryptByPassPhrase` in C# and the IV depends on the version of SQL Server as the implementation changed. You can check out the repo for the code. https://github.com/krcs/SQLServerCrypto