# How to decrypt a string encrypted by SQL Server's EncryptByPassPhrase() in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption

I have an encrypted string and its key, which is created with SQL Server using "EncryptByPassPhrase", how can i decrypt it in PHP?

I have read the documentation of "EncryptByPassPhrase" which states that this is Triple DES encryption of 128 Length. I tried 3DES decryption of PHP but it is not returning the expected output.

Encryption in MS SQL is done with

```
declare @encrypt varbinary(200) 
select @encrypt = EncryptByPassPhrase('key', 'taskseq=10000&amt=200.5' )
select @encrypt
```

I am decrypting it in PHP as following:

```
    function decryptECB($encrypted, $key) {
       $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
       $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
       // decrypting
       $stringText = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $encrypted, 
       MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

       return $stringText;
    }
```

Comment: I assume you'd use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 in the SQL as well

Comment: On my side, i am using MYSQL, where i couldn't find this TSql decryption function.

Comment: @user3783243  I am not syncing from mssql, i am having a number of encrypted strings hardcoded in my PHP script.

Comment: Okay, so mysql isn't in use. It seems like a bad idea to store DB values in your PHP statically. That defeats the purpose of the DB (and also the decryption would be a lot easier by using the inverse function).

Comment: @user3783243 Actually the encrypted string will contain some data which will be used in generating a specific url, upon visiting that url, the encrypted string need to be decrypted in PHP application and the data will be shown on the page. We have no other way but to use that encrypted string generated in sql server with the above mentioned function of TSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of translating [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684733/c-sharp-decrypt-bytes-from-sql-server-encryptbypassphrase#answer-51794958) into PHP.

This is the result:

```
<?php

// SQL Server's DecryptByPassphrase translated into PHP. 
function decrypt(string $data, string $password): ?string {
    // SQL Server <2017 uses SHA1 for the key and the DES-EDE-CBC crypto algorithm
    // whereas SQL Server >= 2017 uses SHA256 and AES-256-CBC. 
    // Version 1 is the SHA1 + DES-EDE-CBC version, Version 2 is the AES-256-CBC version.
    // Version is stored in the first four bytes as a little endian int32.
    $version_bytes = substr($data, 0, 4);
    $version = unpack('V', $version_bytes)[1];

    // Password must be converted to the UTF-16LE encoding.
    $passwordUtf16 = mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF-16LE');

    if ($version === 1) {
        // Key is hashed using SHA1, The first 16 bytes of the hash are used.
        $key = substr(hash('sha1', $passwordUtf16, true), 0, 16);
        $method = 'des-ede-cbc';
        $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
        $iv = substr($data, 4, 8); // initialization vector of 8 bytes
        $encrypted_data = substr($data, 12); // actual encrypted data
    } else if ($version === 2) {
        // Key is hashed using sha256. Key length is always 32 bytes.
        $key = hash('sha256', $passwordUtf16, true);
        $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
        $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
        $iv = substr($data, 4, 16); // iv of 16 bytes
        $encrypted_data = substr($data, 20);
    } else {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid version');
    }

    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, $method, $key, $options, $iv);

    if ($decrypted === false) {
        return null;
    }

    // First 8 bytes contain the magic number 0xbaadf00d and the length
    // of the decrypted data
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 8);

    // UTF-16 encoding should be converted to UTF-8. Note that
    // there might be a better way to accomplish this.
    $isUtf16 = strpos($decrypted, 0) !== false;

    if ($isUtf16) {
        return mb_convert_encoding($decrypted, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE');
    }

    return $decrypted;
}

// A version 1 encrypted string. Taken directly from the Stack Overflow answer linked above
$s = '010000007854E155CEE338D5E34808BA95367D506B97C63FB5114DD4CE687FE457C1B5D5';
$password = 'banana';
$bin = hex2bin($s);
$d = decrypt($bin, $password);
var_dump($d); // string(6) "turkey"

// A version 2 encrypted string. Taken directly from the Stack Overflow answer linked above
$s = '02000000266AD4F387FA9474E825B013B0232E73A398A5F72B79BC90D63BD1E45AE3AA5518828D187125BECC285D55FA7CAFED61';
$password = 'Radames';
$bin = hex2bin($s);
$d = decrypt($bin, $password);
var_dump($d); // string(16) "LetTheSunShining"
```

Sidenote: [mcrypt is deprecated as it has been abandoned for over a decade.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below in query

```
DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('key', [field] )
```

[Reference](http://www.sqlnuggets.com/blog/encrypting-passwords-using-encryptbypassphrase/)

Comment: Read the question again, i am not asking for the decryption in MS SQL. I want to decrypt it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

`EncryptByPassPhrase()` uses a proprietary format that don't seem to have readily available documentation. Best bet for decrypt is `DecryptByPassPhrase()`.

The purpose of this proprietary format is to be used in the database layer of your application - not cross application / network / languages.

If you are dead set of using this format (which i would recommend not to), you would need to obtain the specification of this format, including what kind of key deviation functions are used to turn passwords into actual encryption keys etc.

When you have this specification, you would then have to implement this on your own.

Comment: The only solution that seems now is to connect PHP application to a MS SQL server , run a query for decryption from PHP using the same TSQL decryption function "DecryptByPassPhrase()". I am avoiding this just because the connection & query on MS SQL server will be just for this decryption of the string. I am trying to get the decryption job done with in PHP, but it seems there is no alternative.