# Decrypt data in SQL Server 2014 encrypted by SQL Server 2017 using EncryptByPassPhrase

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I am trying to synchronize data between two databases(SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2017). The Windows application saves the data to SQL Server 2017 database using the `encryptbypassphrase` function. This encrypted binary data is transferred to SQL Server 2014 database. I am unable to decrypt the data using the `decryptbypassphrase` function in SQL Server 2014 database.

Below are scripts to replicate the issue.

In SQL Server 2017

```
declare @clearText nvarchar(max) = 'Hello world!'
select ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Password', @clearText)
```

prints `0x02000000DA28E89D43CC03C11BBDC34041B20BC3627D93CC84E73A83545F379316C0F016DB8A9E22CAABFACC9C70C956217E9604FB69B465C6FF251E397779F1EAEF2464`
and

```
declare @encryptedValue varbinary(max)= 0x02000000DA28E89D43CC03C11BBDC34041B20BC3627D93CC84E73A83545F379316C0F016DB8A9E22CAABFACC9C70C956217E9604FB69B465C6FF251E397779F1EAEF2464
select Convert(nvarchar,DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Password',@encryptedValue))
```

prints `'Hello world!'`

In SQL Server 2014:

```
declare @clearText nvarchar(max) = 'Hello world!'
select ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Password', @clearText)
```

prints `0x010000008DE2368BEE3A899341956117C504F5DC1696A4847D6CFC0A276B2C2D1EFE0052045784B9DC1A9A1E552F4E927794AB0F`

```
declare @encryptedValue varbinary(max)= 0x010000008DE2368BEE3A899341956117C504F5DC1696A4847D6CFC0A276B2C2D1EFE0052045784B9DC1A9A1E552F4E927794AB0F
select Convert(nvarchar,DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Password',@encryptedValue))
```

prints  'Hello world!'

What I am trying to do is transferring the binary data from SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2014 and trying to decrypt the binary data

In SQL Server 2014

```
declare @encryptedValue varbinary(max)= 0x02000000DA28E89D43CC03C11BBDC34041B20BC3627D93CC84E73A83545F379316C0F016DB8A9E22CAABFACC9C70C956217E9604FB69B465C6FF251E397779F1EAEF2464
select Convert(nvarchar,DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Password',@encryptedValue))
```

prints `NULL`

I expect the output to be 'Hello World!'

Comment: It won't work and the reason why is hinted at in the first byte of the output: SQL Server 2017 uses new algorithms for the encrypted data (version 2) which SQL Server 2014 does not support (version 1). An enterprising soul has reversed and shared the [algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794958/4137916); in theory, it's possible to (re-)implement them in T-SQL, in practice, this will be difficult without something like a CLR function.

Comment: Could you also install an SQL 2017 Express instance on the same machine as the 2014 instance and use this to decrypt the data locally?