# C# equivalent of DecryptByPassPhrase

Tags: c#, sql, encryption

I have a requirement to decrypt a value that was encrypted on the database using EncryptByPassPhrase, but without accessing the database.

How do I get the encryption key from the passphrase?

I've looked at

[Replicate T-SQL DecryptByPassPhrase in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617807/replicate-t-sql-decryptbypassphrase-in-c-sharp)

and

[C# Decrypt bytes from SQL Server EncryptByPassPhrase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684733/c-sharp-decrypt-bytes-from-sql-server-encryptbypassphrase?lq=1)

and my code is:

```
public static string AESDatabaseDecrypt(string encryptedString)
{
    passphrase =     "S0meFakePassPhrase01234!";
    encryptedString = "AQAAAOmuc52dnbVwTqEx1kp+4WhI89LYKHh3jg=="; // temporarily hard coded


    // setup encryption settings to match decryptbypassphrase
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    provider.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passphrase).Take(16).ToArray(); // stuck on getting key from passphrase
    provider.KeySize = 128;
    provider.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    // setup data to be decrypted
    byte[] encryptedStringAsByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);

    // hack some extra bytes up to a multiple of 8
    encryptedStringAsByteArray = encryptedStringAsByteArray.Concat(new byte[] { byte.MinValue, byte.MinValue, byte.MinValue, byte.MinValue }).ToArray(); // add 4 empty bytes to make 32 bytes
    MemoryStream encryptedStringAsMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedStringAsByteArray);
    // decrypt
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStringAsMemoryStream, provider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    // return the result
    StreamReader cryptoStreamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);
    string decryptedString = cryptoStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I never did find a solution - we ended up asking the database for the value

Answer (score 1):

Well, I mean, the first thing that leaps out at me is that you're not actually returning a value from your method.  Try adding `return decryptedString;` to the end and see what you get.